# How to make background blur just behind the text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, video

[image: Image with overlaid text. The text is outlined with a white stroke, and the interior of each character reveals the same background image, but with a blur filter applied]

I want blur the text area like this image I have attached but regarding the image I have **video** behind this. I have tried it with mix-blend css property or svg text tag but both didn't work for me. Can you please suggest me how to do this. Please look carefully the image. there its making the background blur where text is written besides the other part is non blurred.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is place two copies of the background image in your SVG, with a blur filter and a text mask applied to the one on top. To get a white outline around the text, you'll need to add the text again. The `<use>` element allows you to add multiple instances of the same item, so you only need to enter the text and background URL once.

Here's an example. It should be fairly self-explanatory.

```html
<svg width="600" height="273" viewBox="0 0 600 273" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  
  <defs>
    <!-- Background image: -->
    <image id="my_background" width="600" height="273" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5e/Forêt_de_Craiva.jpg/600px-Forêt_de_Craiva.jpg"/>
    
    <!-- Foreground text: -->
    <text id="my_text" x="300" y="205" text-anchor="middle" font-family="sans-serif" font-weight="bold" font-size="200">BLUR</text>
    
    <!-- Create a mask from the text -->
    <mask id="text_mask" x="0" y="0" width="600" height="273">
      <use href="#my_text" fill="#fff"/>
    </mask>
    
    <!-- Define a Gaussian blur filter: -->
    <filter id="blur" x="0" y="0">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="2" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  
  <!-- Place the background image: -->
  <use href="#my_background"/>
  
  <!-- Place the blurred image on top, using the text as a mask: -->
  <use href="#my_background" mask="url(#text_mask)" filter="url(#blur)"/>
  
  <!-- Add the text again with a white border around each letter: -->
  <use href="#my_text" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, and can you help me how to add video instead of video inside the SVG tag